# Spring boot @query show parameter table

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I just want to show first name and last name to this project
and I have this entity class and repository
but error is

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    private int id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String phone;
    private Collection<Orders> ordersById;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "lastname")
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "city")
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "country")
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "phone")
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }



    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerByCustomerId",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Collection<Orders> getOrdersById() {
        return ordersById;
    }

    public void setOrdersById(Collection<Orders> ordersById) {
        this.ordersById = ordersById;
    }
```

and my repository is :

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepo extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT firstname, lastname from Customer",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Customer> findAllCustomer();
}
```

but I have this error for use this Query
I use MS DATABASE SQL Server
ERROR is :
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1093
The column name id is not valid.
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause

```
Hibernate: 
    SELECT
        firstname,
        lastname 
    from
        Customer
2020-09-25 23:13:23.634  WARN 7712 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1093
2020-09-25 23:13:23.634 ERROR 7712 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The column name id is not valid.
2020-09-25 23:13:23.672 ERROR 7712 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add mapping , so add this class

```
public class CustomerResult{

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    public CustomerResult(String surname, String lastname){
       this.firstname = firstname;
       this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    // getters / setters
}
```

And add this in your repository

```
@Query("select NEW com.yourpackageClass.CustomerResult(
            o.customer.firstname, o.customer.lastname) 
        from Customer as o") 
List< CustomerResult> findAllCustomer();
```

Hope useful

Comment: I use HQL but I have Error                                                                                                                   `code`    Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.demis.springsql.demo.model.Customer] for value '{Paolo, Accorti}';   `code`

Comment: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.demis.springsql.demo.model.Customer] for value '{Paolo, Accorti}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type

Comment: ``` SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [firstname] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
 [lastname] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
 [city] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
 [country] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
 [phone] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CUSTOMER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO ```

Comment: All this is true when I use it        `code`   @Query(value = "SELECT c from Customer c")  `code`

Comment: @hamednikbakht i notice in your entity not table name add this @Table(name = "Customer", schema="dbo" )

Comment: @hamednikbakht i understand now i will edit my anwser